# Object Tracking with no good feature points

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an object moving along a conveyor line and am trying to use computer vision to track its position.  Some of the objects that will pass through do not have "good features to track."  However, template matching of the corners does seem to work.

If cv::goodFeaturesToTrack isn't giving me good points, am I out of luck?  The corners seem like the distinguishing features, and I was hoping I could track them.  Would template matching (possible taking rotation into account) be the best option to identify corners?

Comment: There's a lot of other feature detectors you could use, e.g. SIFT, SURF, FAST, ORB. Alternatively you could use dense methods (i.e. `findTransformECC`). Template matching would work though; you'd need to create templates with *n* rotations and compare all of them to find the closest rotation, but if you need rotation *and* scaling, you'll have a lot of templates, and since you've given no examples of the object, hard to tell if that's a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a routine like `goodFeaturesToTrack()` is based on image gradients, and gradients are implicitly tied to a single scale. Often an image region that has poor gradients at one scale has stronger gradients at a different scale.  (Indeed the *SIFT* and *SURF* feature detectors mentioned by Alexander Reynolds above make use of filters at varying scales.)

So consider whether you could compute some sort of multi-resolution pyramid and apply `goodFeaturesToTrack()` at varying resolutions.  Also consider whether you could use a multi-resolution dense optical flow scheme like in *calcOpticalFlowSF*.